# Accessing Numpy Array found within an XArray from Satpy

Tags: python, numpy, array, xarray

```
dask.array<shape=(76, 76), dtype=float32, chunksize=(76, 76)>
Coordinates:
    crs      object +proj=utm +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs +units=m +zone=33.0 +type=crs
  * y        (y) float64 4.006e+06 4.006e+06 4.005e+06 ... 3.951e+06 3.95e+06
  * x        (x) float64 4.094e+05 4.104e+05 4.114e+05 ... 4.832e+05 4.842e+05
Attributes:
    sensor:               slstr
    view:                 n
    polarization:         None
    standard_name:        toa_brightness_temperature
    coordinates:          ('longitude_in', 'latitude_in')
    resolution:           1000
    wavelength:           (10.4, 10.85, 11.3)
    file_type:            esa_l1b_ntir
    long_name:            Gridded pixel brightness temperature for channel S8...
    units:                K
    level:                None
    calibration:          brightness_temperature
    name:                 S8_in
    platform_name:        Sentinel-3A
    modifiers:            ()
    start_time:           2018-07-20 09:12:25.111891
    end_time:             2018-07-20 09:15:24.803164
    area:                 Area ID: LS8_duplicate\nDescription: Patch subset i...
    ancillary_variables:  []
```

I have this Xarray which resulted from reading and resampling a NetCDF file using satpy.

```
newscn = scn.resample(area_def, resampler='nearest')
```

Printing the newscn results in an xarray. How can I extract the (76, 76) array with float32 values as a numpy array?

Comment: Assuming your `xarray` array is stored in a variable named `arr` you should be able to access the values (as a `numpy` array) by running `arr.values`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this matter after I loaded the new scene using

```
newscn.load([filename_S8])
```

where `filename_S8 = 'S8_in'` as I want to read the the thermal band 8 from the Sentinel 3 data product. Then I used this line to access the (76, 76) image array as a numpy array:

```py
Arr = newscn[filename_S8]
S3_BT = Arr.compute().data
print(S3_BT)
```